# Orchestration Work Item Sharing Rule Metadata

Tags: sharing-rule, orchestration

I am currently trying to deploy a sharing rule for the Orchestration Work Item via a CI/CD process, but cannot for hte life of me figure out how to get this via metadata. I assumed I could create a file called OrchestrationWorkItem.sharingRules-meta.xml in the sf cli package, and retrieve from org, but that doesn't work.

Do I have to create sharing rules for Orchestration Work Items via manual configuration steps?